# "error 28 from storage engine" during Rails deployment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have been deploying fine with no problems. Today I got this error...

```
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Got error 28 from storage engine: describe active_admin_comments
```

Why? How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be low on disk space on your deployment server. Check the results from `df -h` to see if any of your filesystems are low on space (especially /tmp).

Comment: If you're using capistrano, try running `cap deploy:cleanup` if you haven't done so recently